# Rspec how to avoid allow_any_instance_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Because of rubocop error I want to avoid using `allow_any_instance_of` in my specs.

I'm trying to change this one:

```
  before do
    allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:maintenance_mode_active?).and_return(false)
  end

  it 'returns http success' do
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
  end
```

According to the [rubocop-docs](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop-rspec/1.6.0/RuboCop/Cop/RSpec/AnyInstance) it should be like:

```
  let(:maintenance_mode?) { instance_double(ApplicationController) }

  before do
    allow(ApplicationController).to receive(:maintenance_mode_active?).and_return(false)
    allow(maintenance_mode?).to receive(:maintenance_mode_active?)
  end

  it 'returns http success' do
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
  end
```

Class which I want to test:

```
private

def check_maintenance?
  if maintenance_mode_active? == true
    redirect_to maintenance_mode
  elsif request.fullpath.include?(maintenance_mode_path)
    redirect_to :root
  end
end

def maintenance_mode_active?
  # do sth ...
  mode.active?
end
```

With code above I've got an error:

```
 2.1) Failure/Error: allow(ApplicationController).to receive(maintenance_mode?).and_return(false)
        #<InstanceDouble(ApplicationController) (anonymous)> received unexpected message :to_sym with (no args)
      # ./spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb:15:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

 2.2) Failure/Error: allow(ApplicationController).to receive(maintenance_mode?).and_return(false)

      TypeError:
        [#<RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: #<InstanceDouble(ApplicationController) (anonymous)> received unexpected message :to_sym with (no args)>] is not a symbol nor a string
      # ./spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb:15:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must stub `ApplicationController` to return the `instance_double(ApplicationController)`:

```
let(:application_controller) { instance_double(ApplicationController) }

allow(ApplicationController).to receive(:new).and_return(application_controller)
allow(application_controller).to receive(:maintenance_mode_active?).and_return(false)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! unfortunately it doesn't helped - ```Failure/Error: mode.active
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `active' for nil:NilClass
       Did you mean?  acts_like?``` which means it still using non-mocked `maintenance_mode_active?` method